# ARRAY_TO_STRING in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

PostgreSQL's `ARRAY_TO_STRING()` function allows you to run

```
SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, NULL, 5], ',', '*');
```

and gives you

```
array_to_string

-----------------
1,2,3,*,5
(1 row)
```

Can we do the same using Spark SQL?

What I really need is to have a JSON structure to stay as a string.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing you can get without writing an `udf` is `concat_ws`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

rdd = sc.parallelize(["""{"foo": 1.0, "bar": [1, 2, 3, null, 5]}"""])

spark.read.json(rdd).withColumn("bar", F.concat_ws(",", "bar")).show()
# +-------+---+
# |    bar|foo|
# +-------+---+
# |1,2,3,5|1.0|
# +-------+---+
```

but as you see it ignores nulls. With `udf` you can

```
@F.udf
def array_to_string(xs, sep, nafill):
    return sep.join(str(x) if x is not None else str(nafill) for x in xs)

spark.read.json(rdd).withColumn("bar", array_to_string("bar", F.lit(","), F.lit("*"))).show()
# +---------+---+
# |      bar|foo|
# +---------+---+
# |1,2,3,*,5|1.0|
# +---------+---+
```

but if:

> What I really need is to have a JSON structure to stay as a string

then don't parse it all. For example if you use JSON reader:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

(spark.read
    .schema(StructType([StructField("foo", StringType()), StructField("bar", StringType())]))
    .json(rdd)
    .show())
# +---+--------------+
# |foo|           bar|
# +---+--------------+
# |1.0|[1,2,3,null,5]|
# +---+--------------+
```